# how to update mactex from 2016 to 2017 the correct in macos sierra?

Tags: mactex, texpad

system:

1. macos sierra 10.12.5
2. mactex 2016 default installation

Thank you.

Comment: Download the new version of MacTeX. Install as you did for 2016. You can't update the existing installation.

Comment: so I could move to trash 2016 version.